# jQuery - Display results based on dropdown or radio button selection

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, radio-button, filtering

I'm relatively new to jquery and have found similar results to what i'm looking for, but not spot on.

**What I'm trying to do**
is display a different selection of results based on a drop down or radio button selection. The issue i'm facing is that I want to reference an attribute rather than a class, or paragraph etc.

I have values which are "Years" and I also have a "Year" attribute within the class "product-item". When the drop down selected is equal to the attribute, I want the relevant content to be displayed.

Lastly, I'm having trouble displaying the 2012 content by default.

[Here's the code at js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiusHolden/JbEdE/5/)

```
$("#search-filter").bind("change", function() {   

$(this.value).show();

$('.product-item[year!=""]').hide();
```

​

I'm making an assumption that it's some form of "this" inside the quotation marks [year!=""]

Any help with the above with an explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#search-filter").val('2012');

$("#search-filter").on("change", function() { 

    $('.product-item').hide();

    var val = this.value;

    $('.product-item[year="'+val +'"]').show();

}).change();​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/JbEdE/10/)**

Looks like this was messing your code up..

`$(this.value)`  .. `this.value` gives you a string and you are trying to convert text to `jQuery Object` .. You need a `DOM object` to convert to a `jQuery Object`

Also use .on() instead of `.bind()` as the former is preferred as of jQuery 1.7

Comment: Sushanth - Thank you for the rapid response! That works perfectly! Do you have a moment to explain how the additional change at the end works? Lastly, do you know how to make it display 2012 by default? - Again, thank you for the fantastic quick response.

Comment: @Mattius .. Check the edited post .. You use the .val() to pass the default value and the change() is triggered on DOM ready with this }).change();​

Comment: And the last line is attribute equals selector.. You want to show the .product-item whose year is set to the current value..

Comment: $('.product-item[year!=""]').hide();  in your actual code will hide all the items as the year value is not empty .. Because they have the same class  $('.product-item').hide(); is sufficient .. Also you are not showing the div anywhere.. You just seem to hide it

Comment: That's fantastic. Thank you very very much! - Now I need to attempt to integrate this with SharePoint and XSLT pulling from a SharePoint list. No doubt I'll be back after tomorrow's attempt :)

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not quite sure what you are going for here, I think I can at least help stear you in a direction.

your call to

```
$(this.value).show();
```

is saying im looking for an element in the page with a tag that matches the value (in this case '2009', '2010', etc...)

What you probably want to do is use the attribute search selector

```
$('.product-item[year="' + this.value + '"]').show();
```

that will target the right element

Comment: That makes sense. So essentially "this.value" is looking for the selected value? Whereas before I was specifying something definitive such as 2009 etc? Thanks for your response Selecsosi, appreciated! :)